# Ag-Grid infinite scrolling paginationPageSize not working in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am working on Ag-Grid [infinite-scrolling](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-infinite-scrolling/#example-sorting-filtering-and-selection) and trying to change the page count from **paginationPageSize=100 to paginationPageSize=30 but it's showing 100 rows per page not 30**. check this [Plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/vijE5cICNFqsDOwN) example I have console.log(param) object here endRow count should be 30 but its shown 100.

package.json

```
"react": "^16.8.3",
"ag-grid-community": "^20.1.0",
"ag-grid-react": "^20.1.1",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`cacheBlockSize`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-server-side-model-infinite/#example-infinite-scroll) instead of `paginationPageSize`